# Netlogo: apparent erratic behavior of turtle

Tags: netlogo

I have a model where humans and a door are created. Humans face the door and run to it and exit. The problem is that some humans stop for some reason. Even if only one human is used, it some times reaches the door, and some times it doesn't. What do I have to do so humans always reach the door? This is the [model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3bgw49sjta9yukj/tmp.nlogo?dl=0), and this is the code:

```
globals [ID-door]
breed [door doors]
breed [human humans]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape door "star"
  crt number [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set color cyan
  set breed human]

  new-door

  reset-ticks
end

to new-door
  ask one-of patches [sprout-door 1]
  ask door [
    set color yellow
    set size 2
    set ID-door who]
end

to go
  if count human = 0 [stop]
    ask human [
    move-human
    check-door]
  tick
end

to move-human
    face doors ID-door
    ifelse any? human-on patch-ahead 1
    [rt random 40 lt random 40]
    [fd 1]
end

to check-door
      if any? door-on patch-here [die]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the move-human procedure to the following, and now the model works:

```
to move-human   
    ifelse patch-ahead 1 = nobody or any? other humans-on patch-ahead 1
    [rt random 40 lt random 40]
    [fd 1
     face door ID-door]
end
```

As stated by JenB, `patch-ahead 1` was the problem, so:

a) Because the world has horizontal and vertical limits (it´s not a wrapped space) the line `patch-ahead 1 = nobody` checks the absence of patches when such limits are reached.

b) The line `other humans-on patch-ahead 1` excludes the current turtle as it may be counted because of the possibility that the distance of `1` may still be inside the current patch, like this image:

[image]

Comment: Apart from sorting out the multiple/single names for the breeds (which has no effect), I can't see how this is different. For future people with similar problems, please explain your answer, not just provide code. Perhaps you could just show the procedure that is different and explain what was causing the problem.

Comment: You are right JenB, I have just edited the post with explanation and image

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is `patch-ahead 1`. This looks a distance of 1 in whatever direction the turtle is facing. Imagine the turtle is at the top left corner and looking toward the bottom right corner. The distance to the corner is >1 and the turtle is triggering the 'stay here' check and will be stuck until it is sufficiently turned around so that there is a different patch in front of it.

So you need to get the turtle to exclude itself from the check, which is a job for `other`. Change `ifelse any? human-on patch-ahead 1` to `ifelse any? other human-on patch-ahead 1`.

Comment: Hi JenB, thanks for your answer. It is useful in small numbers, but in greater numbers of turtles, the problem still repeats, large groups get stuck

Comment: That's likely to be a logic problem, not a code problem. Imagine you have such a large number of turtles that there are 5 turtles on every patch. It doesn't matter where a turtle looks, there are 5 turtles already there. What is it that you want the turtle to do? Run your model and when the turtles get stuck, ask it to turn the patch-ahead 1 to colour red and have a look at what is triggering the behaviour.

Comment: I understand it when it is surrounded by turtles, but there are cases in which the turtle has no neighbors and it's still stuck [image] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5p3wapcfcd10cx5/tmp%20view.png?dl=0) – Javier Sandoval 6 mins ago    Delete

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I have just done it many times with 1000 turtles (with the `other` correction) and there's no problem - some clusters get stuck but no individuals. You need to so standard debugging (1) What I have already suggested - run it until it gets stuck and then use `inspect` and actually look at the turtles, get it to turn the `patch-ahead 1` red so you can work out what it is seeing. (2) Use the random seed and change the random seed until it gets stuck and then we can use that seed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your time JenB, will do the debugging. If I find anything relevant will post it here.